# How to step-through the evaluation of an expression in the debugger without creating a script for it?

Tags: rstudio

I know that I can always stick an individual expression in a nonce R script, and then use Rstudio to attach a breakpoint to the expression in the script and source the script.

I'm looking for a way to step-through the evaluation of an expression in the debugger that does not require creating a new script for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by wrapping your expression in a function, then setting the debug flag on your function and running it.

```
foo <- function() {
   # Your expr
}
debug(foo)
foo()
```

You could also use `debug` to set the debug flag on any function called by your expression to start debugging there. More:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/debug.html

Another way to is to include a call to `browser()` in your expression. When that call is evaluated, the debugger will activate.

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/browser.html

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the breakpoint, you can evaluate an expression in the console window.  A few simple expressions look like commands to the browser (`n`, for example), so you might need to enter `print(n)`.

As far as I know this just good for single evaluations of the expression, you can't get it to show up in the Values pane.  R has a way to make variables that correspond to live expressions (see `?makeActiveBinding`), but the RStudio debugger just displays them as `<Active binding>`, it doesn't show the value.

After the edit to the question:  As far as I know you can't do that in R.  But it is very easy to create a script in RStudio, so I'd just do that: `File | New file | R Script`, or the whatever keyboard shortcut works on your platform.

Comment: The original wording of my post was very sloppy, and hence misleading.  I have edited it.  Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution.  Just evaluate the following compound expression:

```
browser(); <ARBITRARY R EXPRESSION>
```

(To be fair, Jonathan does mention this solution in his answer, but I did not understand what he meant when I read it.  I ended up "rediscovering" the same solution on my own.)